# Is it worth adding a new sorting button named "Last Activity" to the Users page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes I need to view who is online, but clicking his/her profile one by one seems to be tedious/cumbersome task. It will be convenient if there is a new button "Last Activity" providing us with a rectangular list of users and the `seen` values (e.g., 20 seconds ago, just now, etc). Viewing 50 users in one page is also helpful, I believe.

Is it worth adding a new sorting button named "Last Activity" to the Users page?

Comment: Am I correct to assume you would not be using that on Stack Overflow? (Seems to me the list would be flooded with many users.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes. I just want it for [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the basic premise of this question is flawed.

> […] I need to view who is online […]

This is not a "need" in the sense that it is required for proper use of the site. In fact i would go so far as to suggest that if this is a "felt need" you are probably doing something wrong. Stack Exchange is not intended to play the role of a social network. You don't come here to interact with specific users, you come here for the content.

There are times when knowing how long it's been since a user was active might help make a decision on how to handle their content.

- Knowing when a specific individual was last seen can occasionally make a difference in knowing how to handle their content. Have they dropped off the map? Are they going to update that post that needs fixing? Have they had a chance to see comments that can now be removed as obsolete?
- Chat rooms also provide functionality to see who is in the room and who is recently active. Knowing this information is relevant to the function of those tools. For the main site, a sorted list of active users is simply not relevant.
- Some information about the most active users is relevant to the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues).

Adding such a feature would prove to be a distraction, subverting the way things work best.